# Is 1/6 G enough for humans to stay healthy?

Tags: the-moon, gravity, colonization, health

Micro-G is known to be detrimental to health in the long-term. However, the Moon is at $\frac{1}{6}$ G (while Mars is at ~$\frac{3}{8}$ G). Is $\frac{1}{6}$ G enough for humans to remain healthy in the long term?

(While there are many concerns that make Moon colonization difficult -- i.e. long night/day cycles resulting in large temperature swings -- please focus on the gravity/health question for now.)

This question may be answered in the long term by [the Space Studies Institute's "G-Lab" program](http://ssi.org/programs/ssi-g-lab-project/).

Comment: Interesting question, I'm not sure if we actually know as we haven't had anyone living in low gravity for any length of time.

Comment: related: [Does lower gravity on Mars make it unsafe and unhealthy for humans?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/42067/does-lower-gravity-on-mars-make-it-unsafe-and-unhealthy-for-humans)

Comment: I have asked this myself for a while, maybe our bodies are much better able to cope in mini-gravity than in micro-gravity. I don't think there are many studies on this (how would there..) but let's see what others know..

Comment: Related but not necessarily a duplicate: [Least artificial gravity needed to maintain health on a one year space trip?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16571/12102) HopDavid's answer is "Finding minimum gravity to keep humans healthy should be a high priority....At this time it remains an open question. We really have only two data points: the weightlessness of someone in orbit and the full g on earth's surface" and it links to their blog post [What is Minimum Spin Hab](http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2013/12/whats-minimum-spin-hab.html)? As Uwe points out, the answer here is the same.

Answer (score 5):

We don't have enough medical data to decide if 0.1667 g is enough or too few. To get enough data we would need hundreds of humans living at 0.1667 g for some decades.

But from what we know now it would be unhealthy to return to 1 g after years at 0.1667 g.

We don't know if a lot of training would be sufficient to keep all bones of the body strong enough for the return to 1 g. What if all bones of the arms and legs got the density needed for 1 g, but some vertebrae are not dense enough?